# How to SUM an amount using CASE but based on the max reference number in another column

Tags: sql, db2

I need to get a count of two types of data (Submissions and Policies) and sum the amount for policies only for a list of agents.  My SQL works, but when there are two records for a single policy in one of the files, it counts and sums an unwanted record, so I need to count and get only the amount for the highest reference number of that policy to be included in the sum.

This is the SQL so far:

```
select a.agsub# as Code, 
sum(case when a.pmstat in ('R', 'Q') then 1 else 0 end) as Submissions,
sum(case when a.pmstat not in ('R', 'Q') then 1 else 0 end) as Policies,
sum(case when a.pmstat not in ('R', 'Q') then (b.pstmap) else 0 end) as GWP 
from cipomf a
inner join alpups b 
on comp# = psconr
and pmprfx = psprfx
and pmplnr = psplnr
inner join ciprar c
on pmprar = paprar
inner join agagtn d
on a.agsub# = d.agsub#
where (PMPRAR = '057' and a.agsub# = '170129')
and (a.pmstat in ('R', 'Q') or a.pmstat != 'Q')
group by a.agsub#, pmprar
order by pmprar
```

RESULTS:

```
CODE     SUBMISSIONS    POLICIES    GWP
170129          7           3       43746.00
```

The SUBMISSIONS count is correct but POLICIES should be 2 and GWP should be 24074.00.

The problem is in the 2nd and 3rd sum statements due to multiple records for a single policy in alpups file:

```
AGSUB#  AMOUNT          REFERNCE#
170129  4232.00     7372236   --policy 1's only record
170129  19672.00    7372239   --policy 2's first record
170129  19842.00    7473004   --policy 2's most recent record
```

I need to only find the highest reference number 7473004 for policy 2, and ignore the lower one 7372239.

I have tried using CTE and nesting a MAX within the sum statements but cannot get the syntax right.

Comment: you need to UNION ALL 3 sselect queries, that will egt the wanted results

Comment: All the 3 rows has 170129 in AGSUB#. How can we know if a row belows to policy 1 or 2?

Comment: Apologies, I needed to simplify by excluding the policy number here but it is in my results.